# Why it says that "Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method"?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, final, local-variables

I have button click listener and in `onCreate()` method I have a local variable like

```
 onCreate() {

 super.onCreate();

 int i = 10;

 Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i++;
        }   
    });
```

Why java asks for to make me final ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When the onCreate() method returns, your local variable will be cleaned up from the stack, so they won't exist anymore. But the anonymous class object new View.OnClickListener() references these variables. Of cause it's wrong behavior so java don't allow you to do this.

After it is final it becomes a constant. So it is storing in the heap and can be safely used in  anonymous classes.

Comment: Ok fine. The reason you mentioned that i is local, it will be destroyed after onCreate() finishes, so onClickListener() will not be able to get the value of i. But if i is final, then I think, it will destroy too after onCreate() destroys. So how it will be used in onClickListener even it is constant?

Comment: The compiler will just replace the use of i in the anonymous class with the values of the constants at compile time, and you won't have the problem with accessing non-existent variable.

Comment: Is it a special case for final variables?

Comment: No, ofc. As you should know variable in java is just a reference to object. If variable isn't final its reference may be set to null. But when it's final you've got no ability to change it. So this variable would still exist after method returns.

Answer (score 13):

Your anonymous inner class refers to its enclosing scope by taking copies of the local variables - if you want to change the value of an int in an anonymous inner class, you need to do some hackery:

```
final int[] arr = new int[1];
arr[0] = 10;
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  arr[0]++;
}
```

Comment: I like this method... Perhaps not clear but "hackery".

Comment: Another hackery: `class Temp { public int i = 10; } final Temp temp = new Temp()` , then use `temp.i`

Comment: Ingenious! Thanks!

Comment: I prefer `org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableInt` 
`final MutableInt = new MutableInt(10)`

Answer (score 13):

Because you're accessing it within an anonymous inner class. You can't do that. You can make it final and then *read* it from the anonymous inner class, but you then can't increment it.

Options:

- Make it an instance variable of the outer class instead
- Make it an instance variable of the anonymous inner class instead
- Use a wrapper - e.g. a single-element array, an `AtomicInteger` or something like that

I would probably favour the second option unless I needed to get at `i` from anywhere else. I regard the third option as a bit of a nasty hack, to be honest.

Comment: While other's only gives reasons, only you are giving solutions(thought may be not expected by the person who asked question :)).... hence upvote

Answer (score 5):

Making the variable `final` is necessary because under the hood, anonymous inner classes like that are simply [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) that compile to a nested class *outside* the scope of the containing method.

This means that none of the variables declared inside of the method are accessible to the inner class, so the compiler pulls another trick - and **copies** the value in a hidden constructor for your class.  To avoid programmer confusion where this copy is not updated to match changes to the variable in the method, it must be final to make sure there are no such changes.

Since your goal here is to have an incrementing integer, and only the reference must be final (the object itself need not be immutable) you could declare a `final AtomicInteger i` and then increment it as you wish from the callback.

Answer (score 4):

Since you need to increment the `i` variable you can't make it final. You could make it a class member instead.